# Dynamic JavaScript Alerts with JWebUnit

Tags: java, automated-tests, htmlunit, jwebunit

I'm using JWebUnit and the system I am testing uses a JavaScript alert that has a dynamic message e.g. "Your application has been submitted with reference ".

Using JWebUnit I am calling WebTester.setExpectedJavaScriptAlert(...) however, I dont know at this point what the expected message will be.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to get around this (other than not using an alert)?

Cheers, Mike